# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL GRAPH API ADO

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, graph, dbcontext

I am currently creating an application with the Graph API and with access to the AD in .NET ASP, everything works correctly in debug mode, but when trying to publish it in an IIS or in Azure as WebApp the error occurs after logging in with the account O365 and redirect to my homepage:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

That happens when trying to generate the cache:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
//mas codigo aqui
.
.
.
Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits, "ADALCache"));
```

The db was generated in an automatic way, so I don't know how it works quite well:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication2-20190809024809.mdf;User Instance=true;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication2-20190809024809;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Already try to add the instance `MSSQLLocalDB` including replace (localdb) with v11.0, the np pipe, change to the name of the server in an IIS and none of this works still marking the same error.

In the case of Azure I understand that there is no localdb so I don't know how it would have to be modified to make it work

I also tried to connect a server but the program itself creates a `.mdf`:

```
WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext
```

and

```
WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext_log
```

Comment: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename

Comment: @SeanLange i change that to 

<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source= server; Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog= aspnet-WebApplication2-20190809024809; uid=user; Password=pass; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> And i got the same error